# Zend-Studio SVN Branch

Tags: svn, zend-studio

I am pretty new using both Zend-Studio as well as SVN.

I have checked out the trunk of my project. How do I commit changes as a branch of the trunk?

Thanks in advance,
fischer

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your project, then go to `Team->Branch...`

It will open **"Create Branch"** window and eventually auto-select **New** content

Then choose a location (using Repo Browser, or put svn URL directly),
something like this : `svn://mysvn.com/myproject/branches/branch_name`
optionaly add a comment,
and click **'OK'**

Now you have a new branch!

To use it,

- you can check the **"Start working in the branch"** checkbox just under the location input before to click **'OK'**,
- or use "Team->Switch" from your project,
- or by creating a new project connected to the new branch!